# Creating a view from two tables, with case and sum on one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I'm having some troubles trying to create a view from two tables, which includes a sum + case for the first table. I've tried multiple different joins/unions, and I can get *just* the XTS table to come over, or *just* the case count scenarios to work, but I cannot get both.

here are the tables. For Table 1, UWI is non-unique. For Table 2, UWI is Unique. new_view is what I'm hoping to achieve for my view.

**TABLE 1**

```
UWI ET
1   A
1   B
1   B
2   B
2   C
2   C
```

**TABLE 2**

```
UWI XTS
1   10
2   20
3   10
4   30
```

**new_view**

```
UWI XTS B_COUNT C_COUNT
1   10   4        3
2   20   3        4
3   10   4        5
4   30   3        2
```

Here's what I'm currently working with.

```
CREATE VIEW new_view AS  
SELECT t1.UWI,  
sum(case when t1.ET='B' then 1 else 0 end) as B_COUNT,  
sum(case when t1.ET='C' then 1 else 0 end) as C_COUNT,  
sum(case when t1.ET='D' then 1 else 0 end) as D_COUNT,  
sum(case when t1.ET='E' then 1 else 0 end) as E_COUNT,  
sum(case when t1.ET='F' then 1 else 0 end) as F_COUNT  
FROM TABLE_1 t1  
INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.UWI, t2.XTS AS TSC  
             from TABLE_2 t2)
on t1.UWI = t2.UWI
group by t1.UWI;
```

Comment: I would suggest you try creating your query first outside of a view, it is much easier to test and play with.  Also looks like you do not need a sub select there, just make it a normal join.

Comment: Yes, new_view is what I'm hoping to get.

Comment: If you post your sample data as DDL+DML it makes it *much* easier for us to play with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample select does not match your sample data, so this is a guess but I think you just need to move the aggregation into an `apply()`

```
select t2.UWI,  t2.XTS, s.*
from Table_2 t2
outer apply (
  select
    sum(case when t1.ET='B' then 1 else 0 end) as B_COUNT,  
    sum(case when t1.ET='C' then 1 else 0 end) as C_COUNT,  
    sum(case when t1.ET='D' then 1 else 0 end) as D_COUNT,  
    sum(case when t1.ET='E' then 1 else 0 end) as E_COUNT,  
    sum(case when t1.ET='F' then 1 else 0 end) as F_COUNT
  from table_1 t1
  where t1.UWI = t2.UWI
  group by t1.UWI
)s
```